# Logic to pic odd dates using python

Tags: python

I have a dates in PDF with following pages with dates. I need the following 08/30/1941 pages alone using python. Looking for logic?

```
{'05/20/2016': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
 '06/20/2016': [4],
 '08/30/1941': [1, 5]}
```

Comment: This is not a service which helps with such questions. Put your code, tell where your problem is and someome will help to fix your code.

Comment: Although this is not the best way to ask question, I think I understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So what you will  need to do is Use PyPDF2 or PDFMiner to extract text from your PDF`s

**PDFMiner**

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
  rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
  retstr = StringIO()
  codec = 'utf-8'
  laparams = LAParams()
  device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
  fp = open(path, 'rb')
  interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
  password = ""
  maxpages = 0
  caching = True
  pagenos=set()

  for pageNumber, pages in enumerate(PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True)):
    interpreter.process_page(pages)

#for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
    #interpreter.process_page(0)

 text = retstr.getvalue()

 fp.close()
 device.close()
 retstr.close()
 words = text.split('\n')
 return words
```

Use the above function to extract text

```
a_list = convert_pdf_to_txt(path)
```

This will return a list and the you can basically go through the elements in list

import re

```
try:
   for index, values in enumerate(a_list):
     date_to_find = re.compile(r"08/30/1941")
     Date_to_find = filter(date_to_find.match, values))
     if Date_to_find == []:
        print("The Date is not available")
     else:
        found = a_list[index]
        Date_to_find = re.match(r"(08/30/1941:)(.*\Z)")
        Date_Found = Date_to_find.group(2)
  print(Date_Found)
except:
   print("There was some error")
```